# CSS-border not lining with an image

Tags: css, image, border, css-float

I'm new to css and have done several exercises on websites such as code academy but am now experimenting with my own page and lack much practical experience.

I know that you can wrap text around an image using "float" but I want to  keep the text in a straight line and border. However, the border and background ignore the position of the image and run behind it. Whats the best way to position then a paragraph and border with an image so that the border will stop against the image?
these are the sections that would be relevant to this:

```
img { 
    margin:5px; 
    float:right; } 
p   { 
    background:white; 
    margin-left:40px; 
    margin-bottom:0px; 
    margin-right:0px; 
    font-family:veranda; 
    border:2px solid #045FB4; 
    padding:5px; }
```

p and img tags have no styling in the body section
example here: http://jimbob.webatu.com/
Any other tips in positioning would be appreciated :)

Comment: The example provides my problem which i have to deal with so you just need to look at the source code: http://jimbob.webatu.com/

Comment: It would be better if you could copy the relevant portions into your question for reference so they are not lost when your website changes.

Comment: ok, #img     {
         margin:5px;
         float:right;
        }

p {
 background:white;
 margin-left:40px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
        margin-right:0px;
 font-family:veranda;
        border:2px solid #045FB4;
        padding:5px;
p and img tags have no styling in the body section

Comment: please elaborate on your intentions for the border. describe the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you mean when referring to the border, but in order for the text to align around the image properly, use:

```css
p {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that will help a lot.